# How can I switch my current session between Unity, Unity 2D, and Gnome?

Tags: unity, gnome, unity-2d, desktop-environments

If I am currently logged in to Unity, is there a way for me to switch my current session to Unity 2D or Gnome without logging out and in again? I know I can restart Unity by running `unity --replace`. Is there an equivalent command for Unity 2D or Gnome that I could run to switch to it? If I am currently running Unity 2D or Gnome, will `unity --replace` switch me back to Unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I would just log out and log back in. Even if you got a script to switch you mid-session, there could potentially be some Unity code still in RAM that might conflict with whatever session you are in. Also, whenever I switch from logging out / in, the Adwaita theme becomes default for Unity.

It would honestly be screwy. May I ask why you would want to switch environments mid-session?

Comment: Mostly I was just wondering if it was possible.

Comment: For Live runs, it would be useful to switch without having to log out, since logging out isn't trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better option is to logout and login with the chosen option .. after some logins with the one of the options it will be the default

Answer (score -2):

I haven't tried it, but you could try `metacity --replace` to go to Gnome.