# Switch from Unity 2d to Unity while logged in

Tags: unity, unity-2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I switch between Unity and Unity 2D without logging out?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69208/how-do-i-switch-between-unity-and-unity-2d-without-logging-out)

It is possible to switch form Unity2d to Unity without logging out first?

I would like to be able to go back and fourth from the two while keeping some applications open. I realize this is just laziness, but I don't want to have to keep opening the application(s) between each version of the DE.

I've searched around the site here and I cannot find a question or answer that touches on this (the logged in part).

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/52491/how-can-i-switch-my-current-session-between-unity-unity-2d-and-gnome - not answer there either, but just so you know it exists.

Comment: ahhh, very good - wonder why my searches didn't turn that up.

Comment: @jokerdino there is no answer to the question, so either is fair game. no answer == no dupe. (according to @jrg)